# SQL Ambiguous column name

Tags: sql-server

I have inherited a large number of SQL reports from someone who left the position I work in. Unfortunately I have had no training in how to use SQL and now after an ERP system upgrade one of the reports is no longer refreshing giving me the error 'Ambiguous column name 'description'. I have no idea how to fix it can anyone help? Thanks

This is the SQL code:

```
select 
G.description
--,MAINACCOUNTID
--,MAINACCOUNTNAME
,G.VOUCHER
,G.ACCOUNTINGDATE
,G.aCCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT AS REBATES
,case when G.HFMCHANNEL='10' then 'Distribution'
when g.hfmchannel='11' then 'Locksmiths'
when g.hfmchannel='12' then 'Retail'
when g.hfmchannel='13' then 'System OEM'
END AS CHANNEL
--,charindex(' ',g.description) as S1
--,charindex(' ',G.description,charindex(' ',G.description)+1)-1 AS S2
--,charindex(' ',G.description,charindex(' ',G.description)+1)-1- charindex(' ',g.description) AS LENTH
--,substring (G.description,charindex(' ',G.description)+1,@LEN) as CUST

--,substring (G.description,charindex(' ',G.description)+1,(charindex(' ',G.description,charindex(' ',G.description)+1)-1)-charindex(' ',G.description)) as CUST
,replace(replace(description,'Rebate ',''),right(description,11),'') as Cust
,c.AccountNum
,d.name as custname
,c.PdsCustRebateGroupId
from __gltrans G 
left outer join custtable c on c.accountnum=replace(replace(description,'Rebate ',''),right(description,11),'') and c.dataareaid='aanz'
left outer join dirpartytable d on d.recid=c.party
where G.voucherdataareaid='aanz' and G.mainaccountid='10110' and G.accountingdate > '1-1-2013' 
--and g.description like ('Rebate%')
```

Comment: use aliases. G.MainAccountID for example.

Comment: Find the word Description and use appropriate ALIAS before the column name. Lets say if column exists in table __gltrans G, then use G.description every where.

Answer (score 1):

These lines:
`replace(replace(description,'Rebate ',''),right(description,11),'') as Cust`
and
`c.accountnum=replace(replace(description,'Rebate ',''),right(description,11),'')`

add the appropriate table alias (ie: `g.description`)

Answer (score 1):

Find the word Description and use appropriate ALIAS before the column name. Lets say if column exists in table __gltrans G, then use G.description every where.

CHeck the revised below query:

```
 select 
 G.description
--,MAINACCOUNTID
--,MAINACCOUNTNAME
,G.VOUCHER
,G.ACCOUNTINGDATE
,G.aCCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT AS REBATES
,case when G.HFMCHANNEL='10' then 'Distribution'
when g.hfmchannel='11' then 'Locksmiths'
when g.hfmchannel='12' then 'Retail'
when g.hfmchannel='13' then 'System OEM'
END AS CHANNEL
--,charindex(' ',g.description) as S1
--,charindex(' ',G.description,charindex(' ',G.description)+1)-1 AS S2
--,charindex(' ',G.description,charindex(' ',G.description)+1)-1- charindex(' ',g.description) AS LENTH
--,substring (G.description,charindex(' ',G.description)+1,@LEN) as CUST

--,substring (G.description,charindex(' ',G.description)+1,(charindex(' ',G.description,charindex(' ',G.description)+1)-1)-charindex(' ',G.description)) as CUST
,replace(replace(G.description,'Rebate ',''),right(G.description,11),'') as Cust
,c.AccountNum
,d.name as custname
,c.PdsCustRebateGroupId
from __gltrans G 
left outer join custtable c on c.accountnum=replace(replace(G.description,'Rebate ',''),right(G.description,11),'') and c.dataareaid='aanz'
left outer join dirpartytable d on d.recid=c.party
where G.voucherdataareaid='aanz' and G.mainaccountid='10110' and G.accountingdate > '1-1-2013' 
--and g.description like ('Rebate%')
```